# How select all values between 2 date by year, month, day columns?

Tags: mysql

In **MySQL** database, I have table with `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DAY` columns.

```
| YEAR | MONTH | DAY | VALUE |
|----------------------------|
| 2018 | 11    | 9   | 1056  |
| 2018 | 11    | 10  | 6582  |
|****************************|
| 2018 | 12    | 9   | 6892  |
| 2018 | 12    | 10  | 5987  |
|****************************|
| 2019 | 3     | 5   |  5693 |
| 2019 | 3     | 6   |  5698 |
```

I need to take all values from the table between 2 date.

Let's say between `2018-11-09` and `2019-03-05` or between `2018-11-10` and `2018-12-09`.

I need to say that unfortunately I can't merge these three column for one `datetime` column. Also the table has partitioning by that 3 columns.

Datatype of columns: `smallint(6)`

Comment: Save yourself a world of pain and store dates using a proper data type

Comment: Why is DAY sometimes 9 and sometimes padded with zero, 05 . What is the datatype of these three columns ?

Comment: Don't want to go into all details, but there are a lot of reasons why I can't make it. I know that it's more easy to use `BETWEEN` operator for one datetime column, but question here is not about that.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya it's my fault. In fact, it must be just `5` instead of `05`. There is no zero. I edit my post. You can check it again. The type of these columns are `smallint(6)`

Comment: See CONCAT - but honestly, a better idea would be to see that whoever constructed this schema gets fired, and then you're free to redesign it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this query should give you the results you want. It creates a date string out of your 3 columns and then uses [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert that into a value that MySQL can compare with the search date strings.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('/', `DAY`, `MONTH`, `YEAR`), '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '2018-11-09' AND '2019-03-05'
```

Output

```
YEAR    MONTH   DAY     VALUE
2018    11      9       1056
2018    11      10      6582
2018    12      9       6892
2018    12      10      5987
2019    3       5       5693
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a3b26729cd700078704867c88d81dfd)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your code return result but the problem is speed. For example weekly slice was processed in 25 seconds which is too long I think. That 3 colomn as I said has partitioning. Is it possible to get data for each day separately and then combine them all. In fact in my real table many records  with the same day, month, year. The difference only in values column. Do you have any ideas about that?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create a string in [MySQL Date format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) (`YYYY-MM-DD`) using string functions such as [`Concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) and [`Lpad()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad):

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE CONCAT(`YEAR`, '-', LPAD(`MONTH`,2,'0'), '-', LPAD(`DAY`,2,'0')) 
        BETWEEN '2018-11-09' AND '2019-03-05'
```

---

Based on further discussion in comments, if you can input the year, month, and day value separately for the given data range(s); instead of creating a date using functions, we can directly use the respective columns instead. This will also allow us to utilize indexes (if defined) on these columns.

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE 
  /* Condition for the month in the start date of the range */
  (YEAR = 2018 AND MONTH = 11 AND DAY >= 9)
    OR
  /* Condition for the rest of the months in start date year */
  (YEAR = 2018 AND MONTH > 11)
    OR 
  /* Condition for the month in the end date of the range */
  (YEAR = 2019 AND MONTH = 3 AND DAY <= 5)
    OR
  /* Condition for the rest of the months in end date year */
  (YEAR = 2019 AND MONTH < 3)
    OR
  /* Condition for the years between the start and end date */
  (YEAR > 2018 AND YEAR < 2019)
```

Above mentioned conditions can be compressed further. But I have written in this manner, for ease of understand-ability.

---

However, it is recommended to create another column to store the date in Date format. If you cannot make changes to the application code, and if your MySQL version >= 5.7, you can look at [Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html), and refer to that in your `SELECT` query instead.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD COLUMN date_col DATE 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS CONCAT(`YEAR`, '-', LPAD(`MONTH`,2,'0'), '-', LPAD(`DAY`,2,'0')) STORED;
```

Then, the `SELECT` query becomes trivial:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE date_col BETWEEN '2018-11-09' AND '2019-03-05'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunatly I can't change the structure of the table. Your code return result but the problem is speed. It's processed too long. In fact in my real table many records with the same day, month, year. The difference only in values column. That 3 colomn as I said has partitioning. Is it possible to get data for each day separately and then combine them all. Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek share the indexing details on your table. From your input date, eg, `2018-11-09`, can you extract the day, month and year out and provide that as an input to the query instead ?

Comment: Yes, I can. As input I can send year, month, day values separately instead of `2018-11-09` if it could solve my problem. You have ideas?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek any updates ? Does it work or not ?